# Structure module - How to display a dynamic page for all my products

Tags: channel, structure

(I am using Structure module version 3.3.6)

Hey guys! 
    I have made this structure so far :

Home -> Products -> Commercial furniture -> Showcase counters
So showcase counters is a sibling of commercial furniture, which the last one is a sibling of products, etc..

So right now when I am on my showcase counters page, the url looks like this : 
http://www.my-web-site.com/products/commercial-furniture/showcase-counters

In my showcase counters page, I created channel of my products but this is where I am stuck, how can I get on my product page with this kind of url :
[...]/products/commercial-furniture/showcase-counters/product-1

I tried this in my showcase counters page : 
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" [...]}
[...]
a href="{title_permalink='/products/commercial-furniture/showcase-counters/'}">{product_name}
[...]
{/exp:channel:entries}

When I created this href, I get the right URL but is there any way to tell which template to use? Cause right now I got this url :
[...]/products/commercial-furniture/showcase-counters/product-1
which is exactly what I want but I can't find where to put a specific template...

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to attach a listing channel to /showcase-counters/ and use a channel tag to call of those entries from the /showcase-counters/ template. Don't forget dynamic="no" as EE requires this to call entries not related to the current URL structure (with or without Structure).